# Route exclude two word in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want route all urls exclude 'admin' & 'login' to page/index

In codeigniter.

I tried: `$route['([^/(?!admin)|(?!login)]+)/?'] = "page/index/$1";`
but its not working. Help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
$route['admin/(:any)'] = "your admin class/$1";
$route['login/(:any)'] = "your login class/$1";
$route['(:any)'] = "page/index";
```